# QuestDB IN Time Range operator with timestamp relative to today

Tags: sql, time-series, questdb

I am trying to use a query [like these ones](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/where/#examples) on QuestDB documentation, using the `IN` time range operator.

I have this query that works fine

```sql
SELECT * FROM trades WHERE timestamp IN '2023-12-22T10:43:00;5s;-1d;7';
```

I am getting all the rows within second 10:43:00.000 to 10:43:05.999 today, and also for the past 7 days.

My problem is that I want to do this relative to the current timestamp dynamically, and all the examples work with a literal string. How could I do this in a simple way?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out a function can be used to compose the literal, so you can use a combination of functions to get your results.

First you want to compose the "reference" timestamp and the pattern after the `;` on the `IN` operator, so you would need to concatenate the dynamic part of the expression relative to the current timestamp, with the fixed time-range pattern.

```sql
CONCAT(TO_STR(NOW(), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'), ';5s;-1d;7')
```

That would extract from the current timestamp the string up to the desired resolution, which is seconds in this case.

That would look OK, but there is a nuance. In the question we want to see what happened in the past 5 seconds, plus the same in the last 7 days. With this approach, the query would return only what happened in the current second for today, and what happened in the 5 seconds before the timestamp in the last 7 days.

So what you need to do is subtracting 5 seconds from the current timestamp, as in:

```sql
CONCAT(TO_STR(DATEADD('s', -5, NOW()), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'), ';5s;-1d;7');
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM trades 
WHERE timestamp IN 
   CONCAT(
      TO_STR(
         DATEADD('s', -5, NOW()), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'
      ), ';5s;-1d;7'
   );
```

Which gives us the desired result.